# Adjust height of button according to navbar html

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar and a button defined in HTML like this :

```
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Hooligans</a>
  <button class="button"><p style="font-family:courier;">drop dead</p></button>
</div>
```

The CSS for the above goes like this :

```
.topnav {
  background-color: #F9FAFA;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #BA55D3;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

.button {
  background-color: #F9FAFA;
  border: 2px solid #BA55D3;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: #BA55D3;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Right now, the best I can do is the button to fit exactly inside navbar. I want it to be smaller than the navbar like the Signup button in the stackoverflow navbar.

**When I set height of the button the text inside the button goes out of the border and when I try padding the button goes bigger.** 
Any help ?

Comment: Try removing the `float` on `a`, remove the `<p>` from the button, and do `.topnav { display: flex; }`

Comment: @0decimal0 Updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<p>` tag inside the button, that is what's causing the unexpected margins. Also, I added `display: flex` to center align the items in the nav:

```css
.topnav {
    background-color:#F9FAFA   ;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #BA55D3  ;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 3vw;
  }


.button{
  background-color: #F9FAFA ;
  border:2px solid #BA55D3;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color:#BA55D3;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: courier;
  font-size: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
      <a class="active" href="#home">Hooligans</a>
      <button class="button" >drop dead</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: What about the media queries used for responsive designs ? Do I have to set the same properties for that also ?

Comment: The a link in navbar adjusts according to smaller screens but the button size doesn't .